# Excel: Using a calculated average from a column in cells in that same column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following data:

```
    Column B    Column C
11  21 Oct      0.87%
12  22 Oct      1.38%
13  23 Oct      0.04%
14  24 Oct      0%
15  25 Oct      0%
```

And so on for every date, with 0% for all dates that haven't occurred yet. I also have a cell (C2) that contains the following formula:

```
{=AVERAGE( IF(B5:B373 < TODAY(); C5:C373))}
```

Which calculates the average of all values in column C up to and including the one for today's date (in column B), so that all the 0% values are not included in the calculation. So let's say today is October 23rd, then C2 would have the value 0.76%.

Each day, I enter a percentage for that date in the corresponding cell, so eventually all the 0% cells will be replaced by the proper values.

Instead of 0%, I want to run some predictive computations based on the average percentage so far. So basically, I want all cells that now contain 0% because I haven't entered the actual values yet to contain the value in C2, making it look like so:

```
    Column B    Column C
11  21 Oct      0.87%  < literal value
12  22 Oct      1.38%  < literal value
13  23 Oct      0.04%  < literal value
14  24 Oct      0.76%  < =C2
15  25 Oct      0,76%  < =C2
```

However, this won't work, because it would create a circular reference between the formula in the cells and the formula in C2.

So I need a formula for C2 that uses a range *up to and including today*. The formula I have now uses the *entire range* and then uses IF to exclude values that lie in the future, which means I can't use the result in the other cells in the column. If I had a formula that limits the range to all cells up to and including today's, I'd be able to use the results in all cells outside that range. I've been messing around with INDEX and MATCH, but I can't figure it out. Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MATCH to find how far into the column of dates is today's date.

```
=MATCH(TODAY(),B5:B373,0)
```

You can use that number with OFFSET to get a range from column C that only contains the values through today.

```
=OFFSET(C5,0,0,MATCH(TODAY(),B5:B373,0))
```

Finally, you get get the average of the values in that range. Enter the following in cell C2:

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(C5,0,0,MATCH(TODAY(),B5:B373,0)))
```

You can now enter `=C$2` in each of the future dates values without getting a circular reference.